# URL Rewriting returns 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to convert this:

`site/read.php?id=6`

to

`site/read/6`

I have tried a couple of solutions found on SO, with the last one being (to output: `site/read/id/6`):
`RewriteRule ^(.*?\.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,N,QSA]`

When I try the second link, it will hang, and apache crashes (LOL).

Not sure if it has a problem with the rest of the .htaccess file, so here is the full code:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^(.*?\.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.+)? $1$4?$2=$3 [NC,N,QSA]
```

I could achieve (with rows 1-4) that no php extensions are showing up, so the address bar currently reads `site/read?id=6`

Can you please point me out where have I gone wrong?

Comment: This is called URL Routing. And I think the best and the easiest way for doing this is to use some frameworks such as `Codeigniter` or `Laravel`. But you can do it yourself without using any frameworks with a little search:  http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/read\.php\?id=([0-9]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . /read/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^read/([0-9]+)$ /read.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Justin, it did not work for me when I've been trying to use all at once, but If I add the last row only, it does exactly what I'm after. Also, for future reference, CSS paths may have to be changed using this method.

Answer (score -1):

I would do dthis in PHP , it is very hard to debug what Apache is getting , it may be that it goes into indefinite loop, did you find anything in apache log files ?
But save yourself a trouble and do it in PHP, if you are using a Framework it is easy to inlcude one PHP that checks for this and redirects to new page if it detects .php in url.